# How to get a well formatted json dump from a Django model nested inside a dictionary?

Tags: django, json, django-models

I'm trying to get data in a view formatted to json to pass to jQuery code.

*I am able to get a json dump from a simple dictionary*:

```
from django.core import serializers


message = Message.objects.get(pk=2)
json_result = serializers.serialize("json", [message,])
```

*I am also able to get a json dump from a Django model*:

```
import json


result = {"message": "hello",
          "age": 3}
json_result = json.dumps(result)
```

*but I haven't been able to get a properly formatted json dump from a Django model nested inside a dictionary*:

```
from django.core import serializers
import json


message = Message.objects.get(pk=2)
json_message = serializers.serialize("json", [message,])

result = {"message": json.dumps(serialized_message),
          "age": 3}
bad_json_result = json.dumps(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json.loads`

```
import json
from django.core import serializers

message = Message.objects.get(pk=2)
json_str_result = serializers.serialize("json", [message,]) #returns string
to_dump = {"message": json.loads(json_str_result)[0], "age": 3} #json.loads
print json.dumps(to_dump)
```